# I need to batch convert Word Perfect documets (.wpd) to word (.doc)

Tags: conversion, batch, microsoft-word, wordperfect

If I do a save as from word perfect, the formatting is retained, and everything is all good.  if I try and open the files in Word 2007, the tables get all screwed up and there are some issues with the text.  I know I can't be the first person to try this.  If anyone else has had success, please let me know what you did and how.  I am really hoping to find a batch conversion tool that uses Word Perfect to save as the current .doc file.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  The wpcvt5 file from download.com is close, but it screws up the tables and makes them stretched out.  There are hundreds of files, so doing it one by one is not an option.

Comment: have you tried RTF?

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to a Linux machine, try the [libwpd](http://libwpd.sourceforge.net/features.html) tools.

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libwpd-tools
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libwpg-tools

They did a good job of getting text out of documents. I haven't tried graphics or tables.

Comment: +1 Worked for me. Provides `wpd2html` `wpd2raw` and `wpd2text`. I also haven't tested fancy documents.